# In addNotification how to change the Apply button

Tags: notifications, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-365

When I try to use `addNotification` method I must use Apply button... But in the action I don't necessarly need to Apply something I can show something or do whatever I want, so I want to know if it's possible to Change the Label (or DELETE) the button "Apply".

here is my code:

```
                var actionCollection = {
                    message:'test text',
                    actions: null
                };

                actionCollection.actions = [function () {
                    for(var j=0 ; j < result_object.id.length ; j++){
                        console.log("test")

                }];

                Xrm.Page.getControl("field_name").addNotification({
                    messages: ['test text 2'],
                    notificationLevel: 'RECOMMENDATION',
                    uniqueId: 'my_unique_id',
                    actions: [actionCollection]
                });
```

and here is a lookup to the apply button:
[image: The Apply Button]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the functionality is limited & predefined when you add notification. You cannot customize more than that.

> The **addNotification** method displays a notification with the messages you specified and two standard buttons: **Apply** and **Dismiss**. Clicking **Apply** executes the action you define; clicking **Dismiss** closes the notification message.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/controls/addnotification#remarks)

Maybe you should try `Xrm.Navigation.openConfirmDialog` for achieving your requirement. [Read more](https://debajmecrm.com/2018/06/01/dynamics-v9-0-show-alert-confirm-error-in-modal-style-with-new-client-api-in-dynamics-version-9-0/)